# Ace Editor manually adding snippets

Tags: javascript, code-snippets, ace-editor

**TL;DR**

I am trying to manually trigger ace editor snippets through a function call, rather than the conventional approach (keyboard keys).

**Explanation**

I need a function that takes in the editor and a snippet string as the parameters, and adds that snippet to the editor. `function addSnippet(editor, snippet)`.

Ace editor supports TextMate-ish snippets.

```
if (${1:condition_name}) {
     ${2:body}
}
```

So when we call this function, it should add the snippet, highlight the snippet markers and select the first one. After filling the first one and hitting tab, the editor should move to the next snippet marker. Just like in the [Kitchen Sink](http://ace.c9.io/build/kitchen-sink.html) example (but I want to add/trigger snippets via a function call instead).

I tried hacking my way through and made [this function](http://pastebin.com/B9T8iMkU). But it's messy and incomplete (doesn't support markers and tab presses). Is there any native method for this? I've seen a few examples using `snippetManager`, but they use keyboard triggers, not manual functions.

Any help regarding this issue would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

After hours of hacks and research, I finally came across the `insertSnippet` function of `snippetManager` in `ext-language_tools.js`, it works this way:

```
var snippetManager = ace.require("ace/snippets").snippetManager;
snippetManager.insertSnippet(editor, snippet);
```

Pretty easy actually, couldn't find it earlier due to lack of documentation.

Comment: The format is TextMate-ish. Just replace all placeholders in the code with `${number:text}` (the number starts with 1). Check out the example in the question.

Comment: can you provide an example of the snippet that you have used

Answer (score 6):

If you don't use RequireJS then the following syntax works as well:

```
ace.config.loadModule('ace/ext/language_tools', function () {
    editor.insertSnippet(snippetText);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `ace.define(...)` for adding your snippet.
The snippets are written in `tex-like` language.

- For Snippet defined at `./src/lib/json-snippet.js`:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
const snippet = '# AddNode\n\
snippet addn\n\
    {\n\
        "nodeName": "${1:node_name}",\n\
        "algorithmName": "${2:algo_name}",\n\
        "input": []\n\
    }\n\
';

export default snippet;
```

```
// import your snippet
import snippet from "../lib/json-snippet";

// SUPER HACK FOR ADDING SNIPPETS
ace.define("ace/snippets/json", ["require", "exports", "module"], (e, t, n) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    (t.snippetText = snippet), (t.scope = "json");
});
```

- Use `brace/mode/{filetype}`, `brace/snippets/{filetype}` for defining file type and it snippets.
- Find existing snippets at `node_module/brace/snippets/` for overriding.

```
import "brace/mode/json";
import "brace/snippets/json";
import "brace/ext/language_tools";
```

For more information check out:

- [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/n46nl94xz0)
- [This](https://github.com/denvash/react-json-snippet-editor) repository

Answer (score 2):

The other answers seem to be kind of old or rather hacky. This worked for me using actual Ace APIs on v1.4.12 (albeit this seems to be totally and frustratingly undocumented).

```js
const snippetManager = ace.require('ace/snippets').snippetManager;
const snippetContent = `
# scope: html
snippet hello
    <p>Hello, \${1:name}!</p>
`;
const snippets = snippetManager.parseSnippetFile(snippetContent);
snippetManager.register(snippets, 'html');
```

Exchange `html` for whatever scope you want.

In the editor type "hello" followed by <kbd>TAB</kbd> to trigger the snippet.