# Insert HTML To Cursor Location To Ace Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ace-editor

I'm not to insert HTML into ace editor via link onclick with jquery. So far as I have been successful, even when trying this script:

Javascript:

```
function insertAtCaret(areaId,text) {
    var txtarea = document.getElementById(areaId);
    var scrollPos = txtarea.scrollTop;
    var strPos = 0;
    var br = ((txtarea.selectionStart || txtarea.selectionStart == '0') ? 
        "ff" : (document.selection ? "ie" : false ) );
    if (br == "ie") { 
        txtarea.focus();
        var range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.moveStart ('character', -txtarea.value.length);
        strPos = range.text.length;
    }
    else if (br == "ff") strPos = txtarea.selectionStart;

    var front = (txtarea.value).substring(0,strPos);  
    var back = (txtarea.value).substring(strPos,txtarea.value.length); 
    txtarea.value=front+text+back;
    strPos = strPos + text.length;
    if (br == "ie") { 
        txtarea.focus();
        var range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.moveStart ('character', -txtarea.value.length);
        range.moveStart ('character', strPos);
        range.moveEnd ('character', 0);
        range.select();
    }
    else if (br == "ff") {
        txtarea.selectionStart = strPos;
        txtarea.selectionEnd = strPos;
        txtarea.focus();
    }
    txtarea.scrollTop = scrollPos;
}
```

HTML Link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="insertAtCaret('ace_text-input','<h1></h1>');return false;">Click Here to Insert</a>
```

Trying to achieve the effect similar to a WYSIWYG editor, only raw HTML is shown in the editor.

Answer (score 2):

use session.insert method to add text to ace

```
var pos = editor.selection.getCursor()
var end = editor.session.insert(pos, text)
editor.selection.setRange({start:pos,end:end})
```

you can also use snippetManager as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/26102713/1743328 and insert a snippet like `'<h1>$0</h1>'`

Comment: You mean something like this? `$( "#target" ).click(function(h1) {
  var pos = editor.selection.getCursor()
  var end = editor.session.insert(pos, text)
  editor.selection.setRange({start:pos,end:end})
});`

Comment: No, I show only the part directly related to Ace, the rest depends on libraries you prefer to use, (e.g. i wouldn't use jquery)